# Summary task in MS Project displaying as task on Gantt chart

Tags: ms-project

I've set some simple color formatting up to distinguish late, completed and future planned tasks on a project plan in MS project for ease of use for sponsors who just want to glance at the plan. The project is split into sub tasks, which have further sub-tasks.

For some reason, despite the summary roll up displaying just fine for the first 2 entered it is now failing on the 3rd entry and displaying as a task rather than summary.

The summary seems to be 'sitting behind' the task on the gantt view but I've no clue why it is displaying as a task.

I'm sure there is an obvious explanation for this but I'm no MS Project guru...
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spotted it as soon as I posted. The summary formatting was set for Active only. Future dating caused the issue. Amended formatting to include planned.

Comment: Feel free to mark as answered after the 3 days grace period :)